# No module named pymssql when using MsSqlOperator

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I'm using Composer version 1.2.0-1.9.0, and I'm trying to use a MsSqlOperator in one of my DAGs. However, when published, Airflow gave me the error: No module named 'pymssql'.

Now, I could install it as a PyPi package, but shouldn't it be supported natively? Even if not, can't I include the mssql subpackage when creating an environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [add additional packages](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package) which are not part of the base environment, in the [Cloud Composer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/composer/environments?_ga=2.193812590.-2132222021.1538157385), when clicking on your environments name you have a tab named PYPI PACKAGES. There you can specify the Python package and version you would like to add to your environment.

You can also do it programmatically by creating a requirements.txt file indicating the additional packages you want and pass it to your Composer environment using the gcloud commands. The needed gcloud command is the one below.

```
gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT-NAME \
--update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt \
--location LOCATION
```